# What type of Excel chart can make summary data easy to see

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a question on how to make a chart with quite a lot of information in it, and at the same time make it look user friendly. I want the manager to be able to see the figures of the quarters/business units and different costs easily without having to study the graph for 1 hour.

I need to present at least:
3 different kinds of costs, 8 quarters & 5 different business units

Does anybody know which chart I should use and how to arrange it?

Comment: Not sure how this website works yet, but thanks Blackwood for your feedback on my grammar :)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not really on-topic for the site.  I'm not sure which site would be a good resource for how best to present information.  But once you decide, we can help if you have questions about how to implement that using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

X-axis will be time (year1q1-year2q4).  Y-axis will be your cost ($, Euro, Rubles, whatever).  You can do business units by color (e.g. all RED are X, BLUE is Y, GREEN is A, YELLOW is B, ORANGE is C, Black is aggregate.  You can then either make three sets of these charts (one for each type of cost), or you could aggregate the costs and do line shading by % (e.g. very light green = cost 1 for green group, medium shaded green = cost 2, etc.).

As someone with a bit of a background in econometrics:  Sometimes conveying a lot of datapoints takes a loooot more than one graph - and even then a lot of your graphs may need... interpretation in the slides.  Good luck!

Comment: XYABC is an odd choice for five arbitrary letters (especially when you’ve already used X and Y).

Comment: Key word is arbitrary, but comments aren't for discussion so I'll just kindly leave it at "Edit it if it bothers you" :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a Stacked Column chart,
and then hack it to make it look like a Clustered Column Chart.

Note: the following instructions and illustrations
are for / from Excel 2013. 
I suspect that you can do the same thing in Excel 2007,
but the procedures might be different.

Make a copy / reflection of your data that looks like this:

```
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    | A  |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    |       | Cost1 | Cost2 | Cost3 |
|  2 | Q1 | Unit1 | 5     | 12    | 60    |
|  3 |    | Unit2 | 42    | 83    | 25    |
|  4 |    | Unit3 | 95    | 1     | 7     |
|  5 |    | Unit4 | 32    | 64    | 8     |
|  6 |    | Unit5 | 51    | 23    | 36    |
|  7 | '  |       |       |       |       |
|  8 |    |       |       |       |       |
|  9 |    |       |       |       |       |
| 10 | Q2 | Unit1 | 94    | 17    | 2     |
| 11 |    | Unit2 | 99    | 17    | 9     |
| 12 |    | Unit3 | 32    | 72    | 64    |
| 13 |    | Unit4 | 94    | 76    | 24    |
| 14 |    | Unit5 | 59    | 82    | 21    |
| 15 | '  |       |       |       |       |
| 16 |    |       |       |       |       |
| 17 |    |       |       |       |       |
| 18 | Q3 | Unit1 | 66    | 26    | 45    |
| 19 |    | Unit2 | 91    | 55    | 10    |
| 20 |    | Unit3 | 11    | 85    | 66    |
| 21 |    | Unit4 | 61    | 28    | 46    |
| 22 |    | Unit5 | 99    | 29    | 44    |
| 23 | '  |       |       |       |       |
| 24 |    |       |       |       |       |
| 25 |    |       |       |       |       |
| 26 | Q4 | Unit1 | 71    | 44    | 60    |
| 27 |    | Unit2 | 6     | 14    | 45    |
| 28 |    | Unit3 | 49    | 37    | 18    |
| 29 |    | Unit4 | 73    | 26    | 75    |
| 30 |    | Unit5 | 81    | 26    | 52    |
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

(and likewise for your second year). 
Note that `A7`, `A15`, and `A23` contain `'`   (apostrophe followed by space). 
This creates an explicit blank value
(in contrast to cells `A3`…`A6`, `A8`, `A9`, etc., which are empty).

Select this entire block of data and insert a Stacked Column Chart. 
You may need to Format Data Series (Fill & Line)
to change one of the colors to something you like.

[image: Format Data Series (Fill & Line)]
  [image: Format Data Series (Series Options)]

While you’re there, go into the Series Options
and change the Gap Width from 150% to 50%. 
(Or smaller or larger; adjust to what you want.) 
I got this result (remember, this is Excel 2013):

[image: Clustered Stacked Column Chart]

The blank rows (7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 23, 24, and 25)
create the space between the quarters. 
Add or subtract blank rows to adjust the amount of space. 
The blank values in cells `A7`, `A15`, and `A23` are important
because Excel seems to interpret Column `A` to mean
that the value in `A2` (“Q1”) applies to Rows 2-6,
the value in `A7` (blank) applies to Rows 7-9, etc.

With this format you can easily see one unit’s total cost for a quarter,
and compare it to the other units’. 
The breakdown into the three individual costs may require a bit of squinting,
but is visible (to people who aren’t colorblind!). 
The trend in overall total costs from quarter to quarter
is fairly easy to see. 
Trends in individual costs and/or individual units (over time) are less clear.